# Running boomerang

Tags: decompiler

I am on Ubuntu 8.04 and I have just downloaded [Boomerang](http://boomerang.sourceforge.net/download.php) and unzip the files into a folder on my desktop.

I `cd` into that folder where the exe boomerang file resides, and typed `./boomerang` and `boomerang`.

However I got the error message:

> unable to execute ./boomerang: No such file or directory.

Why does this happen?

Comment: I am getting a similar error and I haven't resolved this with downloading 32 bit libraries

Answer (score 4):

I guess, you're on a 64 bit system, which mean you must install some x86 libraries to run the program,

to list the libraries the binary is linked against, run `readelf -d | grep NEEDED`

once you know the libraries, just install it for x86 architecture: here are some common and necessary libraries for x86

```
sudo apt-get install libgc1c2:i386 libexpat1-dev:i386 lib32stdc++6 lib32z1 lib32z1-dev
```

now the program should start normally, 
but if it persists, you should see a different kind of error,
try to install those libraries for x86

make sure you have **Qt** installed for the GUI version.

Comment: Running `sudo apt-get install libgc1c2:i386` got the command line version running for me on Ubuntu x64. The error message before was "boomerang: error while loading shared libraries: libgc.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory".

Comment: see my update, to list the libs the binary is linked against, run "readelf -d | grep NEEDED", once you know the libs, just install them for x86.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I'm also aware of `ldd` which lists the libraries, and either give their paths or mark them as not found.

`ldd boomerang-gui | grep "not found"`

Answer (score 0):

The error is most likely because you have a 64-bit system, but the boomerang binaries are 32-bit, and many newer 64-bit systems no longer ship with 32-bit support.

The solution is to install 32-bit support for your system; the method for doing this may differ, however the procedure I used was:

```
sudo apt-get install -y lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0
```

Which should be compatible with Ubuntu and many derivatives, though you should look up the correct procedure for your particular OS version, rather than simply running this command.

However, there may also be a number of other 32-bit libraries that are still required before boomerang will run on a 64-bit linux distribution, but at least once you have 32-bit support installed it can tell you what these are!

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure you unpacked it ??

```
weewee@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ tar xzf boomerang-linux-alpha-0.3.tar.gz
weewee@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ cd boomerang-linux-alpha-0.3/
weewee@ubuntu:~/Downloads/boomerang-linux-alpha-0.3$ ls -l boomerang
-rwxr-xr-x 1 weewee weewee 2376620 Jun 13  2006 boomerang
weewee@ubuntu:~/Downloads/boomerang-linux-alpha-0.3$ ./boomerang
Boomerang alpha 0.3 13/June/2006
Usage: boomerang [ switches ] <program>
boomerang -h for switch help
```